# Should I be able to add a class to a singleton?

Tags: objective-c

I have created a singleton class 'ArrayManager', which does pretty much as it sounds, just for holding and retaining data that must not disappear, while being visible to many other classes. The NSMutableArray *cellArray works as expected, no problem there.

For convenience,  I (attempted) to add a pointer to the class 'MapProps' to the class 'Array Manager'. My thought is as long as I'm just keeping a pointer retained there should be no problem, but Main swears theres no visible interface for it.

I'm still new to objective-c, so maybe I'm on track and it's just a syntax error, or perhaps I'm completely off base. Can some give some feedback as to why this is happening? 
    //MapProps.h
    #import

```
@interface MapProps : NSObject{
    int pixelsX;
    int pixelsY;
    int tileSize;
    int rowsMax;
    int columnsMax;
};
@property int pixelsX,pixelsY,tileSize,rowsMax,columnsMax;
-(void)setPixelsX:(int)x andPixelsY:(int)y withTilesize:(int)tiles;
-(void)displayValues;
@end


//MapProps.m
@implementation MapProps
@synthesize pixelsX,pixelsY,tileSize,rowsMax,columnsMax;

-(void) setPixelsX:(int)x andPixelsY:(int)y withTilesize:(int)tiles {
    [self setPixelsX:x];
    [self setPixelsY:y];
    [self setTileSize:tiles];
    [self setRowsMax:(pixelsX/tileSize)];
    int yScalar = (.875 * tileSize);
    [self setColumnsMax:(pixelsY/yScalar)];
    [self displayValues];
};

-(void)displayValues {
    NSLog(@"PixelsX=%d PixelsY=%d ",pixelsX,pixelsY);
    NSLog(@"TileSize=%d",tileSize);
    NSLog(@"RowsMax=%d ColumnsMax=%d",rowsMax,columnsMax);
};
@end




//ArrayManager.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class MapProps; // include map properties

@interface ArrayManager : NSObject{
    NSMutableArray *cellArray;
    MapProps *mapProps; 
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *cellArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) MapProps *mapProps;


+(id)sharedArrayManager;
-(void)setIntAtIndex:(int)index withValue:(int)value;
-(int)getIntAtIndex:(int)index;
@end


#import "ArrayManager.h"
#import "MapProps.h"

@implementation ArrayManager
@synthesize cellArray;
@synthesize mapProps;


+(id)sharedArrayManager{
    static id sharedArrayManager = nil;

    if (!sharedArrayManager){
        sharedArrayManager = [[self alloc]init];
    }
    return sharedArrayManager;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        mapProps = [[MapProps alloc]init];
        cellArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (int i=0; i <=600; i++) {
            [cellArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        };

    }
    return self;
};

-(void)setIntAtIndex:(int)index withValue:(int)value{
    [cellArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
};

-(int)getIntAtIndex:(int)index{
    return ([[cellArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue]);
};
@end




//Main
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        int x;
        ArrayManager *arrayManager = [ArrayManager sharedArrayManager];

        [arrayManager.cellArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber               numberWithInt:5]];
        x = [[arrayManager.cellArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        NSLog(@"you got %d",x);

        [arrayManager setIntAtIndex:2 withValue:2];
        x = [arrayManager getIntAtIndex:2];

         NSLog(@"you got %d",x);

    [arrayManager setPixelsX:320 andPixelsY:480 withTilesize:16];
```

here I get the message 'no visible @interfor ArrayManager....

```
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, yes, there are other ways to do what I want to here. But in this case, I'd really like to understand and create the best code possible.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the relationship between the classes. You need to import ArrayManager's header file into main.m or the compiler doesn't know that the class exists or the methods it defines.

Comment: Actually it already is, I suppose I should have posted that in, but my question indicated that it is otherwise working, just not the methods from the 'MapProps' class.